# Add wording with a line to a number in a matrix

Tags: matrices, arrows, labels

I'm writing some notes in LaTeX and I would like to do it as I have in the next figure:

[image: Shows the lines (or arrows whatever is easier) marking the numbers insider the matrix with a legend at the other extreme]

Does anyone know of a tutorial I check on how to do it?
All best and thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course `NiceMatrix` environment is absolutely useful and versatile, and I strongly recommend it. However, if you want to do those things a bit more manually, there's alway the `tikzmark` library.

[image: matrix and tikzmark]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

    \[
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \tikzmarknode{A1}{1} & 2 & 1 \\
    3 & \tikzmarknode{A2}{8} & 1 \\
    0 & 4 & 1 
    \end{pmatrix}
    \]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    
        \node[draw,red,inner sep=1pt] (B1) at (A1) {\phantom{1}};
        \draw[red] (B1)  --++ (-1,0) node [left] {pivot};
        
        \node[draw,blue,inner sep=1pt] (B2) at (A2) {\phantom{8}};
        \path (B2) --++ (2,1) node[blue] (C2) {second pivot};
        \draw[blue] (B2) edge[out=45,in=180] (C2);
         
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The environments of the package `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz nodes under the cells, rows and columns of the arrays which are constructed.

Thus, it's possible to use these nodes with Tikz to draw whatever you want with Tikz.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}

$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[margin=3pt]
1 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 8 & 1 \\
0 & 4 & 1 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [red]
    \node [draw,fit=(1-1),inner sep=2pt] {} ;
    \draw (1-1.west) -- ++ (-1cm,0) node [left] {\color{red} pivot} ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because of the nodes PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]